# Internally function returns correctly, outside return value changes

Tags: javascript, function, logging, async-await, return

I'm noticing that the console.log(result) returns the correct value, however console.log(value) returns an object. Shouldn't they be the same?

```
async function getValueFor(key) {
  let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
  console.log('result is ' + result)
  return result || ''
}
```

```
let value = getValueFor('Key')
console.log('value is ' + value)
```

I even tried changing the second block to:

```
let value = 'test'
getValueFor('Key').then(data => value = data)
console.log('value is ' + value)
```

This ends up returning 'test' every time for value, while console.log(result) is still correct.

Comment: I tried using .then() but it still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: your console.log (and all immediate code that follows it) will never be able to get the value "test".  That can only happen asynchronously.

Comment: `.then(data => value = data)` is still executed AFTER `console.log('value is ' + value)` for the reasons given in the link - asynchrony can't be *bypassed*